# BroadcastReceiver for every activities

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my application I have a MainActivity that extends ListActivity. All other my activities extend MainActivity.

In this way in MainActivity I have all settings valid for all my activities and also a BroadcastReceiver that receives intents from a service.

My problem is Preference class that doesn't extend MainActivity and so I lose same intents when user is in Preference window.

Is it possible to set a BroadcastReceiver always on for all the components of my application?

Answer (score 0):

`BroadcastReceiver` triggered by `IntentFilter` which has nothing to do with `Intent`, but with action string.

If `Intent` started with same action - that would start `BroadcastReceiver`. So to start `BroadcastReceiver` from your Preferences activity you just need to start it with the same action as stated in your `IntentFilter` (as here in example: "mypackage.myclass.MY_ACTION"):

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="mypackage.myclass.MY_ACTION"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```